# Load a page with pagemethods inside a div tag inside a MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, load, pagemethods, master-pages

I have a MasterPage which will appear in every page in the application and I'm trying to load a "LoginBox" which uses PageMethods inside a Div tag in this MasterPage

So far I have tried doing as I would do on a Content Page, tried converting it into a User Control and tried using a server side include (< !--#include file="LoginBox.aspx"-->)
None succeeded.

I can see with firebug that the webresources get loaded but the PageMethods javascript isn't created in any of those methods.

I am ***REALLY*** trying to avoid having to create a WebService for this, and moving the LoginBox is not an option, I would rather drop the MasterPage idea, but then maintenance would become hell.

I need ideas or a direction on this.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working successfully with an iframe loaded from javascript, to me it's an ugly solution, but still one. I'm open for better solutions

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('iframe');
        e.setAttribute("src", "LoginBox.aspx");
        e.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
        e.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        e.setAttribute("height", "73px");
        e.setAttribute("width", "225px");
        e.setAttribute("marginheight", "0px");
        e.setAttribute("marginwidth", "0px");
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('loginboxd').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're mashing classic asp with ASP.NET

the point of user controls is to encapsulate exactly what you are doing here.

even then however you will find your attempts to componentize your code will still lead to a messy mess mess. consider moving over to ASP.NET MVC if you can. with that you can do far more suitable and cleaner things to keep your codebase clean.

Comment: Thanks, I will surely look into it. I agree the User Control should suffice for this, but PageMethods doesn't work with it.